# Add a function which returns a search and replace for an attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**app/models/pictures.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Picture = DS.Model.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Picture;
```

This is an example JSON data set:

```
{
 - pictures: [
    - {
        id: 1,
        url: "http://example.com/path/large/example.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to display a smaller version of a picture which is already stored on the server but has `medium` instead of `large` in the URL. How can I add a function to the `picture` model which returns a search and replace for `s/large/medium/` of the `url` attribute?

Comment: To be honest if you have any control over the endpoint it should supply you with a list of size options. Otherwise you're guessing at what picture sizes are available, which is obviously far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use computed property which depends upon `url` property and returns its modified version:

```
var Picture = DS.Model.extend({
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    urlReplaced: Ember.computed('url', function() {
      var url = this.get('url');
      if (url) {
        return url.replace('large', 'medium');
      }
    })
});
```

Then you can use:

`<img src={{model.urlReplaced}} />`

Where model is concrete instance of Picture model.